# Reserve screen space for just one program?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, desktop

I'm running Windows 7, and I've been working on the issue of reserving screen space for only one program for ~3 hours now. I need to reserve it for the Linux Mint taskbar running under VirtualBox in seamless mode. I've tried using DesktopCoral, but it worked a little *too* well because it also prevented VirtualBox from using that space, and it has no way to specify that a certain program should be allowed to use reserved desktop space. I have also tried Hawkeye ShellInit, DesktopX, and WipeOut, which all offer similar functionality, but none of them allow the reservation of screen space for just one program. I have also tried running Worktop, but it just crashes.

Are there any programs that allow me to prevent a part of the screen (more specifically, ~40px on the top) from being covered by other open windows, even when they're maximized (or snapped)?

[image: Guest taskbar being covered]

This shows my current setup, with the bar at the top being covered by maximized windows.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out a Windows Tiling type program.

http://www.winsplit-revolution.com/

http://windawesome.codeplex.com/

http://palatialsoftware.com/plumb/